# Dump from Postgres is not working in HyperSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, pg-dump, hypersql

I have a requirement where I take a dump from **Postgres** server and run it in in-memory **HyperSQL** server.

For example let's consider below query to create a customer table:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
id integer DEFAULT nextval('public.customer_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
name character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
contact character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
address character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying);
```

Above query is generated from **pg_dump** but when I run the same query on HyperSQL it is not able to identify things starting with `::` in this case `::character varying` and `::regclass`.

Couldn't find anything useful in the `pg_dump` or Postgres manual to exclude these things from dump.

For now I am replacing these things with other unwanted things programmatically in Java. Is there any better way to do so?

Note: I am already using `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE;` but it is not helping in this case.

Comment: pg_dump isn't intended to produce a database independent SQL script. It's sole purpose is to write a script that can be used to restore a Postgres database. You should find a different tool that converts your Postgres database to HSQLDB

Comment: If you use an `identity` column in Postgres instead of the (outdated) `serial` columns, then at least you don't need to replace the `nextval()` part

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I completely get it. But if I remove those things from the query and run it in Postgres then it works. It is an optional thing I guess. Is there anything in pg_dump, that I am missing, that can do the same thing for me? I don't know what these keywords are called.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is the default by default.  You can change your table to get rid of the explicit (and apparently pointless) default clause by doing:

```
alter table customer alter name drop default;
```

etc.  I am a little surprised pg_dump doesn't drop it for you.